# keypress event inside another event jumping multimple times

Tags: jquery

I am using a `keypress` event inside another event (click event). This is because it needs multiple variables calculated inside the parent event and because **it should only be fired** after the `click` event.

If the click event is triggered multiple times, then when I press the specified key once, they `keypress` event will be triggered the same number of times as the click event did.

[Living Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jWVck/)

How can I avoid it triggering multiple times? I want the `keypress` event to trigger only once, the call corresponding to the last `click` event, reflecting the number of clicks.

Here's the code anyway:

```
$('#demo').click(function(){
    var demo = "hello";

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {

        //enter key
        if(e.which == 13) {
            alert("Firing multiple times..." + demo);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just call `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.event.cancelbubble = true;`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @DerekHenderson I updated my question. I just want to avoid that behavior :)

Comment: You want one alert, not multiple?

Comment: @DerekHenderson I want the alert corresponding to the last Click, not the previous ones. Sorry if I didn't express well my question.

Comment: @Steve, I've edited your question to make clear what you were asking, basing my edit on your comments and accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cont  = 0;

$('#demo').click(function(){

var demo = "hello";
cont++;

$('#counter').find('span').html(cont);

$(document).unbind().keypress(function(e) {
            ^^^^^^^^|________________________ new update.
    //enter key
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert("Firing multiple times...");
    }
});


});
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks @Arpit. I will accept the answer in 5 mins. Here's the demo working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/imac/jWVck/5/

Comment: You need to unbind the event to stop it. thats it. :)

Comment: Why do I get the message `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'unbind'` in the console? Is there something wrong? You can see it in the link of the first comment to your answer.

Comment: you didn't update the fiddle and therefor I don't know what you changed as you didn't update the answer either. Could you update one or the other? Thanks.

Comment: @Steve Oh!:P .Fiddle Updated now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Working demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/jWVck/6/ *using `.off()` to unbind previous event*

```
var cont = 0;
$('#demo').click(function () {
    var demo = "hello";
    cont++;
    $('#counter').find('span').html(cont);
    $(document).off('keypress').on('keypress',function (e) {
        //enter key
        if (e.which == 13) {
            console.log("Not Firing multiple times...");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. If I click multimple times, the alert will never be shown. I want it to be shown once. The corresponding to the last `click` event.